# Is this correct usage of filters in WordPress

Tags: filters, actions

I am building a plugin and I'm getting doubts whether the code I am using is the correct way of doing things with regards to WordPress hooks and filters.

The scenario is that the code at a particular point needs to know whether to do one thing or another. Simple thing, I could use an option in the plugin's admin. But in order not to clutter the plugin's admin, and given that this option will likely be used by a very tiny percentage of users, I opted to not have a GUI option and instead have this true/false value set via code (the Genesis framework uses this methodology a lot).

We start with the default value in variable:

```
$force_default_thumbnail = apply_filters( 'image_priority', FALSE );
// rest of logic goes here
```

So the variable starts out being FALSE, and a user of the plugin can modify that by using a filter in their theme's functions.php (or as a separate plugin) as follows:

```
add_filter( 'image_priority', 'my_force_default_thumbnail' );
```

That would in turn trigger the following function which is also included in the main plugin file.

```
function my_force_default_thumbnail( $force ) {
    return TRUE;
}
```

When that function is triggered the default value changes to true and the logif of the plugin changes based on that modification.

I hope I explained it well enough, and look forward to your advice.

Comment: It looks right. Have you tested it and does it work?

Comment: Yes it works, my doubt is whether there is a more elegant way to do this, I am still not 100% sure on actions vs filters in such cases.

Comment: For "more elegant", please take a look at [Code Review.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm. Normally, people ask questions here that are more than yes/no questions, but hey, I'm game.

Yes, that code looks fine to me.

Hope that helps! :)

Also note that there is a built in function called __return_true which is there for usage just like so:

`add_filter( 'image_priority', '__return_true' );`

Easy.

Also also note that "image_priority" is pretty generic for a filter name. You should ideally prefix your filter names with the plugin's name, so that filters don't conflict with each other.